# convert list array to json

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on taking a JSON feed and filtering out only the items I want from my list. I'm appending the items I'd like to keep to each list identifier. However, when I convert to JSON the output is incorrect. You can see the ACTUAL OUTPUT example below. The target output below is what I'm actually expecting. I've tried orienting the list with index and records, but no luck.

```
#TARGET OUTPUT
{
   "id":"1",
   "Name":"xxx",
   "Image":"https://xxx.xxx.png",
},
{
   "id":"2",
   "Name":"xx2",
   "Image":"https://xx2.xxx.png",
}



#ACTUAL OUTPUT
{
  "id": ["1","2",]
},
{
  "image":["https://xxx.xxx.png","https://xx2.xxx.png"] 
},
{
  "name":["xxx", "xx2"]
},

#CODE

# JSON feed
{
  "document": {
    "id": "1",
    "image": "https://xxx.xxx.png",
    "name": "xxx",
   },
 },
 {
  "document": {
    "id": "2",
    "image": "https://xx2.xxx.png",
    "name": "xx2",
   },
 },

# create list array
list = {'id':[], 'Name': [], 'Image': []}
links = {'id': [], 'Image': []}

# loop through and append items
def getData(hits):
    for item in filter(None, hits):
        item = item['document']
        list['id'].append(item['id'])
        links['id'].append(item['id'])
        links['Image'].append(item['image'])
        list['Image'].append(item['image'])
        list['Name'].append(item['name'])

    # get first page
    pageNum = 1
    data = getDataPerPage(pageNum)
    try:
        itemsNo = data['found']
        getData(data['hits'])

        while itemsNo > 24:
            itemsNo -= 24
            pageNum += 1
            data = getDataPerPage(pageNum)
            getData(data['hits'])
    
    except:
        print("broken")


    # save list to json
    with open('./output/data_chart.json', 'w') as f:
       f.write(json.dumps(list))
```

Comment: `list` is a reserved name in python, so you should not use it. Try using something else like `lst`.

Comment: Ohhhh that makes a ton of sense. thank you @MichaelM.

Comment: Did that solve your problem?

Comment: Your target output isn't valid. Should it be a list of dict?

Comment: Not exactly. its still apending all ID's in the id, and all images, image. might be @jarmod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you receive multiple JSON objects, those are in the form of a list (so between `[]`). You could:

1. covert JSON string to python dictionary using `json.loads()`
2. filter using the dict
3. dump dictionary into a JSON string using `json.dumps()`

```
input = """[
    {"document": 
        {"id": "1","image": "https://xxx.xxx.png","name": "xxx"}},
    {"document":
        {"id": "2","image": "https://xx2.xxx.png","name": "xx2"}}
    ]"""
input_dic = json.loads(input)
tmp = []
for item in input_dic:
    tmp.append(json.dumps(item["document"]))
output = json.dumps(tmp)
print(output)
```

Hope I got your question.

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% clear what you have or what you want, but with a few assumptions (input is list of dict, desired output is list of dict):

```
json_obj = [
    {
        "document": {
            "id": "1",
            "image": "https://xxx.xxx.png",
            "name": "xxx",
        },
    },
    {
        "document": {
            "id": "2",
            "image": "https://xx2.xxx.png",
            "name": "xx2",
        },
    },
]

desired_output = [x["document"] for x in json_obj]
print(desired_output)
```